# Can you identify this up arrow with rectangle below which just appeared in my menu bar?

Tags: desktop, monterey

This icon just appeared right hand side of the menu bar.  I have no idea where it came from.  Hovering, clicking left/right does nothing.  Does anyone recognise it or know a way I can find out what it is?

I am on MacOS 12.3.1

[image: new icon]

Comment: It looks like the Caps Lock symbol.

Comment: OMG, you're right.  My fancy Logitech keyboard puts the symbol there when caps lock is on.. Never noticed it before :(

Comment: Does it really need additional software for a keyboard? I'd be tempted to run without, if possible, as it's just something else to go wrong.

Comment: @benwiggy It usually does if the keyboard offers non-standard features.